# ERROR 1064 (42000) works on WebSQL but not on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, web-sql

When using mysql to run this query,

```
select country_code, Avg(freq) as frequency
from 
(
    select t1.country_code, t1.freq
    from avg_call country_code_final t1        
    union all
    select t2.country_code, t2.freq
    from calls_at_one xx_country_code_frequency t2 
)
group by country_code;
```

I received an

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
>       select t1.country_code, t1.freq
>       from avg_call country_code_final t1
>       union all
>       select t2.country_code, t2.freq
>       from calls_at_one xx_country_code_frequency t2 
>   )
>   group by country_code;'`

I tried running this on WebSQL it work.

Comment: `select country_code, Avg(freq) as frequency;` < remove the semi-colon

Comment: @Fred-ii- oops, accidentally added that. Not intended at all. Unfortunately, I still need help ㅠ ㅠ

Comment: well, there might be a hidden unicode quote (and/or space) being introduced somewhere, seeing the error `near '`, best guess I can come up with. I can't see how that would fail, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: at the very least you need a table alias, after your second closing bracket put an arbitrary string eg `table_alias`

Comment: This: `from avg_call country_code_final t1 ` is not valid SQL syntax. Is there supposed to be a `_` between `avg_call` and `country_code` ?